# Casting consumer generic type to another type

Tags: java, casting, consumer

Please first look at my code. I get an error in the BolBFS constructor when I want to create an object:

```
Error:
Required type is : Consumer<Node<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo>>
Provided type is : Consumer<BolNode>
```

I know I can't cast `consumer<T>` to `consumer\<? extends T>`, but I don't know why, and how should I handle this problem?
If I change Node<Identifire, Data> to N, I have another problem in the **adj()** method in class BFS.

```
Error:
Required Set<N>
Provided Provided Set<Node<Identifier, Data>>
```

This is my code:

BolBFS.java constructor:

```java
public BolBFS(TraverseDirection dir, BolNode root, Consumer<BolNode> consumeEachBol, Predicate<BolNode> setFlagCondition, Predicate<BolNode> stopCondition) {
    BFS<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo, BolNode> bfs =  new BFS<>(dir, root, consumeEachBol, setFlagCondition, stopCondition);
}
```

BolNode.java:

```java
public class BolNode extends Node<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo>
```

BFS.java:

```java
public class BFS<Identifier, Data, N extends Node<Identifier, Data>> implements Serializable {

    protected TraverseDirection dir;
    protected volatile Queue<Node<Identifier, Data>> nextToVisit;
    protected volatile boolean flag;
    protected volatile Set<Object> visited;
    protected Consumer<Node<Identifier, Data>> consumer;
    protected Predicate<Node<Identifier, Data>> checker;
    protected Predicate<Node<Identifier, Data>> stopCondition;
    protected volatile Map<Object, Node<Identifier, Data>> predecessor;
    protected volatile Map<Integer, Set<Node<Identifier, Data>>> levels;
    protected volatile Map<Object, Set<Object>> adjList;
    protected volatile Map<Object, Node<Identifier, Data>> idMap;

    public BFS(TraverseDirection dir, Node<Identifier, Data> root, Consumer<Node<Identifier, Data>> consumer, Predicate<Node<Identifier, Data>> checker, Predicate<Node<Identifier, Data>> stopCondition) {        this.dir = dir;
        this.flag = false;
        this.checker = checker;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.stopCondition = stopCondition;
        this.predecessor = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.levels = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.adjList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.idMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        idMap.put(root.getId(), root);
        levels.put(0, Stream.of(root).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        logic(root, consumer, checker, stopCondition);
    }
    protected Map<TraverseDirection, Set<N>> adj(N node) {
        Map<TraverseDirection, Set<N>> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        result.put(TraverseDirection.ANY, node.getChild());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Node.class:

```java
public abstract class Node<Identifier, Data> implements Serializable {
    public abstract Set<Node<Identifier, Data>> getChild();
    }
```

Comment: I am thinking of it as `? extends T` means "something, but very specific thing that extends from T". A,B,C... can match T if all extends T, and all of them can be exactly T. But if you cast it to `?` then which one of possible matches is it?

Comment: Why are lots of your fields `volatile`?

Comment: Why do you declare `N extends Node<Identifier, Data>`, then use `Node<Identifier, Data>` in the constructor parameter types?

Comment: @Antoniossss I said `? extends T` to send my concept, I mean something extends from T, In my example `? = BolNode` and `T = Node`.

Comment: no, T is T and BolNode is BolNode. ? is "something" even if your current scenario you can deduct what it would be.

Comment: @AndyTurner because before refactoring I was using N instead of `Node<Identifier, Data>` and it was ok in constructor, I was trying to fix unchecked warning and I went to the depths of hell with this problem. :)

Comment: Not related to your question but all the maps can be final, the volatile content is synchronized by the ConcurrentHashMap, you don't need the map itself to be volatile. I have no idea what you're trying to do with all these volatile fields but if you really have multiple threads accessing all these objects concurrently, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `Consumer<BolNode>` is not a `Consumer<Node<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo>>`, for the same reason that [a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po). More specifically, a `Consumer<BolNode>` expects that it will always be passed a `BolNode`, whereas a `Consumer<Node<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo>>` might be passed any subclass of `Node<String, ChildFlightConsignmentInfo>`.

You have declared a type parameter `N extends Node<Identifier, Data>` in the `BFS` class, but then not used it in the constructor parameter types. I would suggest trying:

```
public BFS(
    TraverseDirection dir,
    N root,
    Consumer<N> consumer,  // Or Consumer<? super N>
    Predicate<N> checker,  // Or Predicate<? super N>
    Predicate<N> stopCondition) {
```

Comment: @vahidghasemi please edit this into your question. It's impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got another error in the code. (post edited)
should I ask my question in another post?